# <jsp:scriptlet> not working in Firefox (JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.0.0)

Tags: javascript, jsp, jdeveloper

I am using `<jsp:scriptlet>` to print some javascript in the page and it seems working when using IE, but when using Firefox, nothing is printed.

I am using JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.0.0. In older JDeveloper versions, I don't see this issue.

Thanks,

Shawn

Comment: Can you share your source code? Any errors / console warnings in your browser?

Comment: In jspx page: <af:outputText id="webTrendsTags" value="#{bk_mainBean.webTrendsTags}" escape="false"/> and in the backing bean, it prints something javascript: <script type="text/javascript"> ... and in IE, it prints those scripts, but in Firefox, nothing there at all. The JDEV console doesn't show error message at all.

Comment: I switched to <af:outputText> in JDEV 12c, same issue in Firefox / Chrome

Comment: For some reason, the javascript is not displayed when trying "View page source" in Firefox / Chrome. But when checking after F12, it shows the javascript is in the page.